# Link my backend rpc server with front end web form applications

Tags: go-ethereum, microsoft-azure

I am using azure, i have 2 resources - one is the web form app (visual studio)and other one is the ubuntu vm running geth. I tried alot of things to make the front end to connect with the backend. Is there any way that the rpc server can be made accessible by the front end web app on azure. Or is there any way to make the server on the internet so that i can connect to it. Or is there any easily available open node?

Comment: What is the command used to launch geth ? Have you openned the machine ports to allow traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

[Infura](https://infura.io/) provides an open RPC node which you can access at `'https://mainnet.infura.io/'`.

*Note that this url is throttled and is subject to some limitation. In order to bypass these limitations you will need to register on the [Infura website](https://infura.io) and receive and access token, which you can then append to the url.*